# How to solve typescript errors in react app while firing in local server?

Tags: typeerror, react-typescript

my package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.89",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.11",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.17",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "12.6.9",
    "@types/qrcode.react": "^0.8.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/react-scroll": "^1.5.4",
    "@types/react-select": "^3.0.5",
    "arc-text": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "countries-and-timezones": "^1.0.1",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.2.4",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.26",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "qrcode.react": "^0.9.3",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-arc-text-fix": "0.0.0-development",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "react-bootstrap-timezone-picker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-datasheet": "^1.4.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-new-window": "^0.1.2",
    "react-phone-code": "0.0.4",
    "react-print-components": "^1.0.4",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.16",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-timezone": "^2.4.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.3.2",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.6",
    "typescript": "3.2.1"
  }
```

The errors I am seeing in my project are below:

```
F:/neyaatek/ft/ft-web-app/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
TypeScript error in F:/neyaatek/ft/ft-web-app/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(326,13):
Type expected.  TS1110

    324 |         // too complex for TS. So we type it as a general visitor only if the key contains `|`
    325 |         // this is good enough for non-visitor traverse options e.g. `noScope`
  > 326 |         [k: `${string}|${string}`]: VisitNode<S, Node>;
        |             ^
    327 |     };
    328 |
    329 | export type VisitNode<S, P extends Node> = VisitNodeFunction<S, P> | VisitNodeObject<S, P>;


TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@types/react-router/ts4.6"' has no exported member 'withRouter'.

TS2307: Cannot find module '@material-ui/pickers'.

TS2307: Cannot find module '@material-ui/pickers/constants/prop-types'.
```

I am trying to set up a one year old react app in my computer. I am using node 12 version. I want to run the app successfully in my machine and work on it. Can somebody help? I have tried to upgrade the version of react, react-router, react-router-dom and @types/react, @types/react-dom to latest versions.